# Get notified when child window is open and finished loading

Tags: javascript, ajax, window.open

What is the way to check when a child window is open and it's content is all received from the server and is fully loaded?

What I am doing is showing a ajax notifier .gif becuase this window.open is about 15 seconds and I need to give the user something to look at.

Here is one way I've tried, but the ajax loader notifier closes as soon as the windows opens, which is to be expected but I've got it like this for example purposes.

```
AlumCloud.showAjaxLoader();

 if (window.open(['/api/rollup?f=', getResponseFormatOpt(), '&ids=', options.ids.join(','), '&lbls=', options.addLbls].join(''), '_blank',
                 'width=' + WIN_OPEN_WIDTH + ',height=' + WIN_OPEN_HEIGHT, false)) {

  AlumCloud.removeAjaxLoader();
    };
```

Would be nice to have a callback when the window is open and fully loaded with it's content.

However, I can set an interval if there is another to keep checking if the window is loaded.

---

Here is something that gets me extremely close but does not work.

```
    var url = ['/api/rollup?f=', getResponseFormatOpt(), '&ids=', options.ids.join(','), '&lbls=', options.addLbls].join('');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: true,
        complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

           var w = window.open("", '_blank', 'width=' + WIN_OPEN_WIDTH + ',height=' + WIN_OPEN_HEIGHT, false);

            w.document.body.appendChild($('<iframe src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="100%" >').get(0));
        }
    });
```

**It works if I append that iframe to the current window, but does not work if I try to append the iframe to the new window that I'm opening.**

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

**JS**

```
$.ajax({

    url: "YourajaxcallURL",
    data: "DataIfany",
    beforeSend: function () {
        // this is where we append a loading image
        $('#ajax-panel').html('<div class="loading"><img src="loading.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#ajax-panel').empty();

    },
    error: function (data) {
        $('#ajax-panel').empty();
    }
});
```

And add this to your **HTML**:

```
 <div id="ajax-panel"> </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#ajax-panel {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: at this point I'm point the url of the window directly to the pdf on the server. that example will not work.